# Are ASP.Net Control IDs bad for SEO and page size?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, seo

ASP.Net controls (e.g. asp:Label) generate messy html ids (e.g. ct100_ct100_Yabba_Dabba_Doo_FinallyTheRealId). Yeah, they're ugly, but someone told me today that they're also:

1. unfriendly for SEO
2. increase the page size

I half believe 1) and half disbelieve. I know that certain id names (e.g. "header") are keywords that search engines will use to generate meta information, but I'm more skeptical that a span with id="author" really affects SEO. I'm willing to admit that I could be wrong.

On point 2), I'm at least 90% skeptical. Most of page size is not the html characters and I truly wonder if 100 longer ids would even add 1kb to a page size.

I can go with one of two approaches. *Which approach would you take?*

**Approach 1)**

```
<asp:Label id="lblAuthor" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

with code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblAuthor.Text = "Superman";
```

or 
**Approach 2)**

```
<span id="author"><%# Eval("Author") %></span>
```

with code behind

```
public string Author { get; private set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Author = "Superman";
```

On the one hand, 1) doesn't generate the nasty ids. On the other hand, I've always hated untyped strings in asp.net web forms and avoided them when I can. Also, if a page has 30+ elements, I end up with 30 page properties, which makes me feel uneasy. (Side note: a reason to love how the model works in the MVC pattern).

We're working in .Net 3.5.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I would be interested on what grounds they're considered unfriendly to SEO. I also agree with you that the page size change is trivial compared to what is likely to be a lot of CSS/JavaScript/Image content.

Comment: Having just left a web marketing company, my point of view is that the SEO crowd is absolutely insane and will latch onto anything Google says and take it to the extreme. They're batty, ignore anything they say.

Comment: Anthony - LOL. Though I think I won't pass that advice on -- after all, our team lead recently got sent to several days of company SEO training.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram You're spot on. Half of the things spread about SEO are just plain wrong and cannot be proven to be correct. If Google hated control ID's it would give the majority of ASP.NET pages a disadvantage and make it worthless for web development. Obviously, Google would never discriminate openly against the .NET platform and with all the crappy ASP.NET sites out there with decent SERPs it's impossible to say that it could have any effect at all.

Comment: The only possible way that I can see ids being important for SEO is that they're used to identify important keywords (such as those in a div with id="header") versus those to ignore, such as id="ad1". Of course, if you're trying to maximize SEO, you'll be adding meta tags for those keywords anyway so I don't get the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach 3)

```
<span id="author"><asp:Literal id="author" runat="server" /></span>
```

Code behind:

```
author.Text = "Dr. Seuss";
```

`asp:Literal` is what the name implies, a control that renders only the text you send it; no more, no less.

Comment: Both you and Mathieu submitted essentially the same answer at about 1 minute apart. I'm giving you the points, because yours came first. I did give click up both answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 3)**

```
<span id="author"><asp:Literal id="litAuthor" runat="server" /></span>
```

with code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   litAuthor.Text = "Superman";
}
```

this solves you id problem with Labels. For other elements, good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

SEO: No

Page size - SURE. I mean, the strings are longer, so they take more space, so page size if longer.

Update to .NET 4.0 then you can override the ID's with stable short ID's.

Comment: Any evidence, such as article links on your "SEO:No"? As to the second point, as soon as we're on IIS 7, to heck with web forms I'm pushing for MVC.